# Timer running in a jar used as library

Tags: java, asynchronous, timer, jar, boot

I would like to write a small program that runs a timer at startup. Then, I would like to export this program to jar file and import it into a java web project as a library. But before I would like to reassure myself of one thing:
- Is it possible to launch the Timer when the jar is started, when the jar file is deployed, ie just after the import? If yes, how?

Thank you for giving me your opinions and directions.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to write a small program that runs a timer at startup.
>   Then, I would like to export this program to jar file and import it
>   into a java web project as a library. But before I would like to
>   reassure myself of one thing: - Is it possible to launch the Timer
>   when the jar is started, when the jar file is deployed, ie just after
>   the import? If yes, how?

The jar format does not provide any hook by which you could specify such a thing, and in general, jar files are never themselves "started" or even "imported".  Metadata, resources, and classes can be read from a jar, as requested or needed, by a `ClassLoader` or otherwise, but the VM does not emit any events or signals by which you could detect that.

If there is some particular class in your jar that is characteristic of it -- maybe the timer class itself -- then you could give that class a static initializer that will start an instance of the timer.  That will be triggered when the class carrying the initializer is *loaded*, however, which is not necessarily the same thing as when the jar is first opened or read.  Possibly, though, you can choose a class that is certain to be loaded sufficiently early.

Comment: thanks John! can i choose a main class for this? or, how can i load class sufficiently early?

Comment: @FiokoSoft, since you are in control of the classes you put in the jar, you can put such a static initializer in any class you like.  Ensuring that the class is loaded early is an entirely different matter, however.  It depends on the context in which the jar is used.  The jar itself gives you no influence over that, except if it is an application jar, *used* as such.  Then the `Main-class:` entry in its manifest would be relevant.

Comment: thanks @John!Now, I put the launch code of my Timer in the static void main method of my main class and i compile my program. Then, i import the jar file into other java web project. when, i excecute some method of my web project which concern my jar program nothing happens, the timer don't start.

Comment: Please, can you give other some matter to do this static Initializer. Could you give me a piece of code?

Comment: @FiokoSoft, what makes you think that the `main()` method of your main class would be invoked in the context of a web project?  What you describe is an appropriate approach for an application jar, when *used* as an application jar, but it is unlikely to be useful otherwise.

Comment: As for static initializers, @FiokoSoft, if you don't already know about them then [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+static+initializer).

Comment: precisely, it is a notion that is foreign to me. So, I will ask goole as you propose it to me. thanks for your time!